# SSIS ERROR “Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type”

Tags: ssis

I'm using ssis to load data from syabse into sql server and have a datetime column that keeps throwing the following error:
Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Processed_Date] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].
The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."

In the inputs and outputs I’m using [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] type for Column [Processed_Date]. There are other DT_DBTIMESTAMP columns in the load, but Processed_Date is the only one throwing the error.

In the source, Processed_Date has a default value of convert(datetime,convert(varchar,getdate(),101)+' '+convert(varchar,getdate(),108)) so not sure if this is the issue.

Data type in the destination table is datetime. Here are the min/max values from source: 6/28/2012 10:06:26.000 PM 7/6/2012 1:19:05.000 PM

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Tracy

Comment: What's the data type for the `Processed_Date` column in the destination table, and what are the `MAX` and `MIN` values of the column in your source table?

Comment: Data type in the destination table is datetime. Here are the min/max values from source: 6/28/2012 10:06:26.000 PM 7/6/2012 1:19:05.000 PM

Comment: I was sort of hoping for a straight forward out-of-range date value in the source column, but that doesn't seem to be your issue. :(

Comment: What is the datatype of the Processed_Date in the metadata of the input to OLE Destination?